# Click on scatter plot dot and get to corresponding row [Excel]

Tags: excel, plot, scatter-plot, vba

I have a table with x and y values which are used to create a scatter plot.

I'd like to be able to click on a dot on the scatter plot and be able to retrieve the row corresponding to the point. Perhaps using a macro?

Comment: There is Chart Events that you can program when you click on the chart sheet tab with the right button and choise "View Code" menu. Try to see "Chart_MouseUp" event.